# GROUP BY not sorting properly when using joins

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I want to see only one record from the joined table fr_movements with the newest sched_date yet I am always getting the oldedst sched_date.  Since the ORDER BY sorts by the sched_date and I am grouping by the people.ID I am getting only one record from fr_movements as expected,  just the wrong one.

```
SELECT `fr_movements`.`ID`, fr_movements_list.movement_type, 
   fr_movements.sched_date, fr_movements.comp_date, people.firstname, people.lastname
FROM fr_movements
LEFT JOIN people ON people.ID = fr_movements.`people_id` 
LEFT JOIN fr_movements_list ON (fr_movements.move_type_id = fr_movements_list.ID)
WHERE fr_movements.org_id = 25 AND fr_movements.move_type_id IN (54,53,52,51,50,55)
GROUP BY people.ID
ORDER BY people.org_name, fr_movements.sched_date ASC
```

Anybody know how to do this properly?

Comment: It's not your JOINS that are the problem, the problem is you are using GROUP BY incorrectly.  GROUP BY is supposed to be used with an aggregate function, since you are not aggregating the data and are not grouping by all of the columns, MySQL will decide what value it wants to return for the columns not included in the group by clause. My suggestion would be to read the MySQL Docs on the use of the extension to GROUP BY - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: If you load sample data into sqlfiddle.com, I'm sure someone will help you rewrite your query. Also share what you expect the final result set to look like.

Comment: The OP IS trying to use an aggregate function (MAX). They just don't know how!!!

Comment: Without seeing proper DDL's it's a little hard to see what you're aiming at. But basically, this is a GROUPWISE MAX problem, widely covered in this 'forum' (if we're allowed to call it that), as well as elsewhere on the web - including the MySQL manual itself.

Answer (score 0):

as @bluefeet mentioned

> you are using GROUP BY incorrectly. GROUP BY is supposed to be used with an aggregate function

You need to put all columns after `GROUP BY`, but it is complicated. I think `DISTINCT` might help you. like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT people.org_name, `fr_movements`.`ID`, fr_movements_list.movement_type, 
       fr_movements.sched_date, fr_movements.comp_date, people.firstname, people.lastname
    FROM fr_movements
        LEFT JOIN people ON people.ID = fr_movements.`people_id` 
        LEFT JOIN fr_movements_list ON (fr_movements.move_type_id = fr_movements_list.ID)
    WHERE fr_movements.org_id = 25
        AND fr_movements.move_type_id IN (54,53,52,51,50,55)
) x
ORDER BY org_name, sched_date ASC
```

If not works, would you post your data & schema into sqlfiddle? That makes us happy.